# Copying attribute table for each layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, fields-attributes, agriculture

In QGIS I'm trying to edit attribute tables for a corn planting prescription. I have 50 layers (fields) that all need to have the same attribute table layout. Is there any way to create a template attribute table and then fill in the values needed for each different layer?

Comment: In GIS softwares, layer and field are different phenomena, and 'field' means "a table column".  Do you mean that? Your question a bit unclear.

Comment: My apologies, when I said (field) I mean one of our crop fields not a table column. Sorry for that ambiguity!

Comment: When you have 50 crop fields with the same attributes you would normally create one layer with 50 features. One real-world crop field is represented by one feature. All the features can and will have different attribute values and geometries.

Comment: I'll try this, my only worry will then be uploading into planting software. Unsure on the capability of the software to import several real world field prescriptions in one file. It's a good starting point though, thank you.

Comment: Presumably you will have a unique field for crop field id in the structure. Then all you have to do is select only the features for that crop field and then export with export only selected- i.e. those for the crop field in question.